# How to create a guard for guest users in Angular to authenticate with sanctum only

Tags: angular, typescript, sanctum

I have a forum like application that uses Laravel for the back-end, sanctum for authentication and Angular for the front-end

I need guest users to access the home page and request the list of questions to show from the Laravel api but I need to prevent them from accessing the editor page for creating questions

the api endpoints are protected by `auth:sanctum` middleware so guest users need to request a token to access the api.

Instead Users authenticated also via front-end (logged in Users) should access guests forbidden routes.

For logged in users I've created this guard in angular:

```js
export class AuthGuardGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService : AuthService){ }
  activate = false
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    this.authService.getUser()
      .subscribe(
        res => this.activate = true
      )
    return this.activate;
  }

}
```

but it's not clear to me how should I handle guest users authentications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the read routes of my api free from sanctum middleware like this:

```php
Route::prefix('user')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->put('/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
});
;


Route::prefix('questions')->group(function () {
    Route::get('', [QuestionController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/{id}', [QuestionController::class, 'show']);
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('', [QuestionController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('/user/{userId}', [QuestionController::class, 'getByUserId']);
    Route::get('/category/{categoryId}', [QuestionController::class, 'getByCategoryId']);
});
```

and making an auth guard for logged-In only routes:

```js
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    this.authService.getUser()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.activate = true
        },
        err => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login'])
          this.activate = false
        }
      )
    return this.activate;
  }
```

and protected the /editor route like so:

```js
  {path: 'editor', component: EditorDetailsComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuard]},
```

with this, users that have no account can read the questions but they are redirected to login if they try to create a new question by accessing the /editor route